# Laravel: DB Query returns stdclass instead of array

Tags: mysql, laravel

I've got the following:

```
$srv = DB::table('ads')
    ->join('ad_service','ad_service.ad_id', '=', 'ads.id')
    ->select('ads.id')
    ->whereIn('ads.id',[45789,46531])
    ->get();
    Log::info($srv);
```

and log info gives me

```
  49 =>   stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'id' => '46531',
  )),
  50 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'id' => '46531',
  )),
  51 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'id' => '46531',
  )),
```

What I would like to have:
return the entry ONCE, there are multiple entries with this id in the "ad_service" table , and i would like to retrieve it once. 
its a many to many relationship.
also biggest problem, what is this stdclass set state?
I was expecting something like:

```
array('id' => '46531', ...,)
```

thanks guys.

EDIT:
Solved it using Eloquent:

```
$srv = Ad::whereIn('id',[46696,48982,...MORE IDS HERE])->get();
```

this returns not an object but a collection itself. i do not really know what @ourmandave meant with "you get a collection with std class objects" i mean obviously i could see that but i do not really know why i got it, and why i get it as i wish using eloquent.
Any answer to that would be appreciated:
Why does DB:: return this std class stuff and Eloquent returns the "wanted format"?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Im using laravel version 5.2 in this project

Answer (score 1):

You're actually getting back a lararvel Collection.

From the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results)

> The get method returns an Illuminate\Support\Collection containing the
>   results where each result is an instance of the PHP stdClass object.
>   You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a
>   property of the object:
>
> ```
> foreach ($users as $user) {
>   echo $user->name; 
> }
> ```

There's a lot of methods they provide for collections to treat them like arrays.
(https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods)

You might also try the distinct() method to get back one of multiples.

```
  $srv = DB::table('ads')
    ->join('ad_service','ad_service.ad_id', '=', 'ads.id')
    ->select('ads.id')
    ->whereIn('ads.id',[45789,46531])
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

Comment: Currently getting: array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'id' => '45789',
  )),
  1 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'id' => '46531',
  )),
)  

Need it in this form though:
{ "key" => "val , "key2" => "val2" ...}
any idea? :/

Comment: i mean 
{ { "key" => "val" }, { "key2","val2"} }

Answer (score 1):

If you just want one record you could try:

```
$srv = DB::table('ads')
        ->join('ad_service','ad_service.ad_id', '=', 'ads.id')
        ->select('ads.id')
        ->whereIn('ads.id',[45789,46531])
        ->first();
```

Change the get to a `first()`. The reason you are getting multiple records is because `get()` returns a laravel `collection` of your ads.

Comment: what i need is 1 array , with 1x the entry.  this one returns an error with "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Answer (score 0):

To convert a model and its loaded relationships to an array, you should use the `toArray` method. This method is recursive, so all attributes and all relations (including the relations of relations) will be converted to arrays

```
$srv = DB::table('ads')
    ->join('ad_service','ad_service.ad_id', '=', 'ads.id')
    ->select('ads.id')
    ->whereIn('ads.id',[45789,46531])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Print array:

```
Log::info($srv);
```